# Differencies in git webhook payloads

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, webhooks

I would like to integrate (means to be notified when push) git repositories to my project via webhooks and found huge differencies in implementations for instance between Github and bitbucket. The JSON data POSTed via webhook are different ( https://pastebin.com/YFCU0An5 bitbucket vs https://pastebin.com/aMNRRyFa gitbub).

For example - 
username: 
**bitbucket**

```
"owner": {
  "username": "XXX",
```

**github**

```
"owner": {
  "name": "XXX",
```

Am I missing a main idea of webhooks or are they really different "as they want"? How should I approach the "universal git integration via webhooks" solution then?

Thank you

Comment: The payloads will be different. They are two different companies and they have different API responses/implementations. You'll have to handle them separately.

Comment: The idea of webhook is just subscribing to certain events. It doesn't guarantee similar JSON payloads for different services.